# File Manager In Xfce

Tags: files, xfce, tooltip

In file manager in xfce, I'd like to disable tooltips if there's a way. Also, 
in file manager preferences > behavior > middle click, 
open in new tab or new window is broken,
it doesn't matter which I select, the behavior is the same, 
folders and files not opening in a new window or new tab, 
only the current window. Please help.

Comment: Did Ctrl+Shift+o work for open a selected folder in new Window and Ctrl+Shift+p to open in a new tab? For me (on Xubuntu 14.04) double middle click opens a selected folder in Thunar in a new window and Ctrl+"double middle click" opens the selected folder in Thunar in a new tab. What is your Ubuntu version is it an dist-upgrad (13.04 to 14.04) or something else?

Comment: I have folders set to open on single click. What you mentioned doesn't work for me. I"m not familiar as to what thunar is ? I'm running a clean install of Xubuntu 14.04. I'm more interested in getting rid of the tooltips at this point than having folders open a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to:
 
`~/.gtkrc-2.0
gtk-enable-tooltips = 0`

This however will disable toolips in general.
Source: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7714

Comment: Be sure though to log out and back in again after making the change.